# Hobbits prosthetic Ears and feet

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, adaptation-comparison, hobbits

Reading that Martin Freeman [kept some souvenirs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2310332/trivia?item=tr2071639)  from filming the hobbit (his prosthetic ears and feet) had me thinking:

Was there any reference in the books that hobbits had pointy ears and over-sized feet?

I remember there being lines suggesting they had hairy feet, and thick soles to allow them to walk over stones. When reading the book I just assumed they had normal human feet like say [Cody Lundin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cody_Lundin), someone who just walks barefoot a lot.

Are the over-sized feet created for the film so people don't think "why don't they just wear shoes?"
And was there any suggestion that hobbits had ears different to humans?

Comment: should probably look at the artwork of Lee and Howe - that's where a good majority of the visual style for the films came from

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes and no.

Tolkien drew a picture of Bilbo in his home (note the pointed ears and horned and hairy, **but not oversized** feet and toes);

[image]

And in his own words when asked for a pen-sketch of the typical hobbit;

> I picture a fairly human figure, not a kind of 'fairy' rabbit as some
>   of my British reviewers seem to fancy: fattish in the stomach,
>   shortish in the leg. A round, jovial face; **ears only slightly pointed
>   and 'elvish'**; hair short and curling (brown). The feet from the ankles
>   down, covered with brown hairy fur. Clothing: green velvet breeches;
>   red or yellow waistcoat; brown or green jacket; gold (or brass)
>   buttons; a dark green hood and cloak (belonging to a dwarf).
>
> <sub><sup>[The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien, 35 (#27)](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_27)</sup></sub>

As far as the feet are concerned, there are multiple descriptions of their hardness and hairiness but only one family is described as having feet that are large, the others are "*neat and nimble*"

> “The Harfoots were browner of skin, smaller and shorter, and they were
>   beardless and bootless; their hands and feet were neat and nimble …
>   the Stoors were broader, heavier in build; their feet and hands were
>   larger … the Fallohides were fairer of skin and also of hair, and they
>   were taller and slimmer than the others …”
>
> <sub><sup>The Fellowship of the Ring</sup></sub>

Comment: Ha, that's funny, when I first heard Nicol Williamsons audio version of the Hobbitback in the 80s, I imagined a rabbit like creature. I guess that's what happens when you start out with "In a hole in the ground, there lived a hobbit..."

Comment: And 'hobbit' sounds like 'rabbit' so one can see easily the assumption @MikeyMouse - very true!

Comment: Where is this picture from / where was it published?

Comment: From "The Art of the Hobbit" by J.R.R Tolkien. The book features a wide range of original artworks by the author : http://www.amazon.com/The-Art-Hobbit-J-R-R-Tolkien/dp/0547928254?tag=gmgamzn-20

Comment: When you go around barefoot all the time, there's less of a need to keep your toenails cut short.

Answer (score -4):

Their feet aren't necessarily oversized in the movies.  All of the actors that played Hobbits are 5'7" and shorter. They might wear a size 8 or 9. The prosthetics may have upped them to a 12 or so, still in the realm of possibility.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: no, it addresses the assumption that the feet in the movie are oversized; they are not.